# Adding Options in Ektron Workarea

Tags: ektron

I am working in Ektron 8.6.

What is the best approach to add some additional options in the ektron workarea.My requirement is like adding an additional option in the settings TAB of a Content.Is it recommended to go and make change in the corresponding physical page? or is there is any alternative approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would see if you could use Metadata to model the new settings you need. That way, no need to change Ektron code, and no coding required.

Another option would be to create a Smart Form for the settings you want, and then add a content selector metadata to link a content to a settings smart form.

I would go with option A if these settings are going to be different on every page (e.g. "ShowLeftHandColumn") or option B if large number of pages are going to share similar settings (e.g. "SalesDepartmentAdvertismentSettings")